# Manually Installing ActiveX component

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8, activex, cab

I'm trying to view a surveillance camera system.  The remote access is available through a website, and that website seems to need to download a CAB file full of goodies to let me view the cameras.

On some of my systems this install process goes over nicely.

On a few, particuarly the ones with slower Internet, I get into an endless-loop of: going to the page, waiting a long period of time (I assume this is where its downloading the CAB file), clicking yellow bar to allow it to "Install this CAB file for all Users" and the page reloading.  It never pops up with the Window saying "Are you sure its cool to Install this stuff?"

Is there a nice way I can side-step this with a little code?  I've downloaded the CAB file and extracted its contents.  It's full of DLLs and a SetupScript.vbs.  I've tried to just let the SetupScript.vbs run, and I've tried to manually register the DLLs with `regsrv32`.  I've even copied the required .OCX and .INF files to the `C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\` and modified the registry to mimick one where the install went smoothly.

Despite this, when I visit the webpage, it still takes forever and then goes back into the loop described above.

What APIs do I need to call to "properly" register this component so IE can see it?  Or is there something more simple that I'm missing?

Could someone please point me in the right direction to solve this?  The browser is IE8, the OS is Vista.

Thanks!

Comment: Try running regsvr32 on the OCX files too.

Comment: @Nathan, any chance you wanna make that an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: you can answer it for yourself with his answer (you probably already knew this). I would suggest just deleting the post but I didn't see any duplicates for your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Windows 7 64-bit I copied the OCX files to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and then ran:

```
regsvr32 /s C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PLUGINNAME.ocx
```

The ActiveX plugin worked fine when I launched IE without prompting for an install.

Comment: It makes sense to omit `/s` key, otherwise you won't get any error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Typo from above and i've noticed with some installations of Windows 8.1 you need to run regsvr32 from the sysWOW64 root folder:

```
%SystemRoot%\Syswow64\regsvr32 /s C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pluginname.ocx
```